# Running JavaScript module returns SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to run a javascript package `simple-statistics` from

- command-line via `node`
- `jupyter notebook` via javascript kernel

In either case, I'm trying to import the module via:

```
var ss = require('simple-statistics')
```

but receiving the error:

```
C:\Users\...\simple-statistics\index.js:8
export { default as linearRegression } from './src/linear_regression';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

I have tried multiple solutions such as

- updating `.babelrc` to include multiple configurations of

  ```
  {
    "presets": ["latest"]
  }
  ```
- updating `package.json` to include code very similar to the above
- pretty much everything I've found on SO

I'm new to Javascript, and to be honest it's a bit overwhelming navigating the sheer quantity of modules that may be related to the problem (`babel`, `webpack`, etc.).

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction, or help me what I assume is a simple issue. I'm drawing a blank. Thanks!

Comment: What version of Node.js is installed on system?

Comment: Can you post the entire output of including that error?

Comment: The `main` of the package on npm is `dist/simple-statistics.js`, so I'm not sure how you're getting your system to try to load `index.js`. It doesn't appear to be for public consumption for Node. https://github.com/simple-statistics/simple-statistics/blob/master/package.json#L45

Comment: As the previous comment said, the `index.js` is not the file you need to run. Apparently before you need to run the command `npm run build` after which `node ./dist/simple-statistics.js`

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick response. In particular, I didn't know about the `index.js`, and running `npm run build` (which required me to install additional packages e.g. `rollup`) fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved (for this case).

As pointed out by [loganfsmyth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/785065/loganfsmyth) and [Ruslan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2102906/ruslan), I failed to create the distribution build.

Everything worked after running `npm run build`.